# A question about Dedekind schemes and proper morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, dedekind-domains, valuation-rings

The following is Exercise 15.3 of Görtz-Wedhorn *Algebraic Geometry I*:

> Let $S$ be a Dedekind scheme with function field $K$ and let $f: X\to S$ be a proper morphism of schemes. Then the canonical map $X(S)\to X(K)$ is a bijection.

For example, the map $X(S)\to X(K)$ being injective means ${\rm Spec}\ K\to S$ is an epimorphism of schemes. I'm no idea to prove it, even for $S$ affine. For subjectivity, I can only see (using valuation criterion for being proper) that a morphism ${\rm Spec}\ K\to X$ extends to a morphism ${\rm Spec}\ \mathscr{O}_{S, y}\to X$ ($y$ being the image of ${\rm Spec}\ K\to X\to S$ but don't know how to extends to the whole of $S$.

I'm also wondering if the maps need to respect morphisms to $S$, namely if we need to consider $X_S(S)\to X_S(K)$ instead of $X(S)\to X(K)$.

Comment: Just to tell that I asked the authors and they really mean $X_S(S)\to X_S(K)$.

Answer (score 2):

Injectivity is because $X$ is separated. The locus where two morphisms $S \to X$ agree is a closed subscheme and if it contains the generic point, it's everything.

For surjectivity, we can "spread out" the morphism $Spec K \to X$ to a morphism $U \to X$ from an open subset $U \subset S$ and then use the valuative criterion to fill in the finitely many missing point.

**Edit:** Here are some more details. So spreading it out is the general procedure where if we have an integral ring $R$ with fraction field $K$, a finite type scheme $X$ and a $K$ point of $X$, we can extend it to a $R_{f}$ point because there will only be finitely many denominators. For an easy example, suppose $X = \mathbb A^1$ and $R = \mathbb Z$ and the rational point is $t \to 1/2$. Then, there is an obvious way to think of this as a $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ point.

So given a rational point of $X$, we can extend this to a map from an open subset $U \subset S$ to $X$. Since $S$ is a Dedekind scheme, there are finitely many height one primes in the complement of $U$. Consider the local ring $R_{\mathfrak p}$ at one of these primes which is a DVR.

By the valuative criterion, we can get a $R_{\mathfrak p}$ point of $X$. Again, by spreading out, we can extend this to a map from $V \to X$ for $V$ another open subset of $S$ that contains $\mathfrak p$. On the other hand, the maps from $V \to X$ and $U\to X$ match on their intersection (by the same argument as for injectivity) and so we can extend this to a map $U\cup V \to X$.

Repeating this process for any points still left over, we get a map $S \to X$ that extends our rational map.

Comment: Thanks! Injectivity agree! For surjectivity, I don't know how to "spread out" and "fill in the finitely many missing point", could you give more details? And do you use $X(S)\to X(K)$ or $X_S(S)\to X_S(K)$?

Comment: OK, I think by "spread out" you mean extending morphisms as in Proposition 10.52 of Görtz-Wedhorn.

Comment: I think it's useful to try and work it out yourself. Anyway, I will try and write more in a hour or two if you are still stuck (busy right now).

Comment: OK, thanks, I will try to work it out myself and tell you if I still stuck.

Comment: I used some results on extending rational morphisms and schematically density to show $X_S(S)\to X_S(K)$ is a bijection, but I still don't know if you are meant $X(S)\to X(K)$. Even so, I'm still wondering how to use the valuative criterion to fill in the finitely many missing point; I can't make it work. It would be grateful if you can also add that to your answer.

Comment: Hi, I added details. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I think again about your answer, I think you found some element in () maps to (), but may not under the canonical map ()→() induced by the inclusion of the generic point of $S$, e.g. that may happen if the image point $y$ of ${\rm Spec}\ K\to X\to S$ is not the generic point of $S$. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: No that's right. This is why everything should really be relative to the structure maps to S which answers the other question you had.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread your comment. I think the element we found in X(S) maps to the given point in X(K) under the canonical map. I also don't think we need to use X_S(S) to X_S(K) but currently our proof works only in this case. For instance, if you allow the affine line with double origin as a dedekind scheme and take X to be the affine line over it, injectivity is no longer true in the absolute sense. (I might be making mistakes since I am tired, please check everything I'm saying)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109654/discussion-between-lao-tzu-and-asvin).